# binary input output problems

Tags: c++, c++11

i am trying to learn how binary file works . When i input anything above 127 its giving me wrong answer 
 . Please explain me why this happening ..

```
int x[10] = {124,45,21,35,45,25,26,254,12,32};

fstream BCD("Random.bin", ios::binary | ios::out  | ios::trunc);

if (!BCD.is_open()) {
    cout << "opps<<";

}
else
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        BCD.put(x[i]);
    }

}
BCD.close();

 int out[10];
fstream file("Random.bin", ios::binary | ios::in);

 char C;
int i = 0;
while (file.good())
{
    file.get(C);
    out[i] = ( int)C ;
    i++;
}
```

i just want store some value in between 0 - 255 as binary and read back 
and How can i get a file size  if i accessing  some file is there any way to find its size first and read data based on the size. I only know one way that is in the above code a don't know i am doing correct or not 
plz correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when reading, the value is being treated as signed, or negative.  You need to use :-

```
char C;
int i = 0;
while (file.good())
{
    file.get(C);
    if( file.good() ){
        out[i] = static_cast<int>( static_cast<unsigned char>( C ) );
        i++;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately as I thought earlier `fstream::get` takes char only, so we need it to be a `char`.

So we read it as a `char`, then reinterpret it as `unsigned char`.

Finally replace the C cast `(int)` as a C++ cast `static_cast` to get to an integer value (signed, but positive).

There also needs to be a check to ensure that the buffer is not overrun, when reading beyond the last element

Comment: "There also needs to be a check to ensure that the buffer is not overrun, when reading beyond the last element" how cani do that